# Publish symbols for Nuget package

Tags: nuget, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-artifacts

I am using VSTS and have set up a build script that also publishes to the VSTS internal (private) Nuget feed.  All good so far.

Now I want to publish the symbols somewhere so that I can debug those nuget packages. Just FYI I am open to another way of doing this if there is a better or easier way!

So I found the [Index Source & Symbols Publish](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/build/index-sources-publish-symbols) article and associated build step.  This looks great! But I don't understand how to make it publish somewhere and where that somewhere should be? Do I have to create an Azure file share and how do I give it appropriate permissions so the build agent can copy it? I feel like the docs at this point are either beyond my understanding or are missing vital information

If anyone could help me I'd be very grateful. Thanks.

P.s.
I have included my build order and activities here if that helps give context

[image: Build steps]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to publish symbols, for example:

1. Publish to a shared folder (make sure it can be accessible from build agent)
2. Publish to a folder, then copy or upload to other server through Azure File Copy, Windows Machine File Copy, cURL Upload files etc… steps/task.

You can specify symbol location in VS if you want to debug with these symbol files. More information, you can refer to: [Specify Symbol (.pdb) and Source Files in the Visual Studio Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241613.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I know this, I guess my question really is *how* do I do this? For example how do I make #1 accessible to the build agent?

Comment: @Chris If you are using on premise build agent, you can share a folder that can be accessible from Intranet. If you are using Hosted Build Agent, then you can use Windows Machine File copy to copy files to your server (Internet IP), or copy file to azure through Azure File Copy. On the other hand, you can include symbols to artifact through Publish Build Artifact step, then others can download artifacts in build detail page.